# TypeError: 'frozenset' object is not callable

Tags: python, hashlib

I was trying to install `hashlib` python module on a gcloud instance.

I couldn't because of this error:

```
Collecting hashlib
Downloading hashlib-20081119.zip (42kB)
100% |################################| 51kB 8.3MB/s 
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from setuptools.extern.six.moves import filterfalse, map
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/extern/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pkg_resources.extern import VendorImporter
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/message.py", line 16, in <module>
    import email.charset
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/charset.py", line 13, in <module>
    import email.base64mime
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/base64mime.py", line 40, in <module>
    from email.utils import fix_eols
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    import random
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 49, in <module>
    import hashlib as _hashlib
  File "hashlib.py", line 115, in <module>
    f()
TypeError: 'frozenset' object is not callable

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-MduVxt/hashlib/
```

So, I tried with `easy_install` instead:

```
sudo easy_install hashlib
Searching for hashlib
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/hashlib/
Best match: hashlib 20081119
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/74/bb/9003d081345e9f0451884146e9ea2cff6e4cc4deac9ffd4a9ee98b318a49/hashlib-20081119.zip#md5=46e59db6d5cac34b3344ef0c30d0897f
Processing hashlib-20081119.zip
Writing /tmp/easy_install-EENwwt/hashlib-20081119/setup.cfg
Running hashlib-20081119/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-EENwwt/hashlib-20081119/egg-dist-tmp-ukAV7B
no previously-included directories found matching 'build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'dist'
no previously-included directories found matching 'RCS'
no previously-included directories found matching 'CVS'
no previously-included directories found matching '.svn'
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Moving hashlib-20081119-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Adding hashlib 20081119 to easy-install.pth file
Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hashlib-20081119-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
Processing dependencies for hashlib
Finished processing dependencies for hashlib
```

Everything seems to be fine, but THEN, after this, every time I run `pip` or `easy_install` for whatever reason it shows me this:

```
pip list
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
from pip import main
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
from pip.exceptions import InstallationError, CommandError, PipError
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/exceptions.py", line 6, in <module>
from pip._vendor.six import iteritems
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
vendored("cachecontrol")
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
__import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/wrapper.py", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 3, in <module>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 35, in <module>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connection.py", line 14, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 80, in <module>
import mimetools
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
import tempfile
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 35, in <module>
from random import Random as _Random
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 49, in <module>
import hashlib as _hashlib
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/hashlib.py", line 115, in <module>
"""
TypeError: 'frozenset' object is not callable
```

And same goes for `easy_install`:

```
sudo easy_install -m hashlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/easy_install", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
import email.parser
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
from email.feedparser import FeedParser
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
from email import message
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/message.py", line 16, in <module>
import email.charset
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/charset.py", line 13, in <module>
import email.base64mime
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/base64mime.py", line 40, in <module>
from email.utils import fix_eols
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/utils.py", line 27, in <module>
import random
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 49, in <module>
import hashlib as _hashlib
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/hashlib.py", line 115, in <module>
"""
TypeError: 'frozenset' object is not callable
```

Any ideas on how to uninstall or fix it?

I can run any of those commands in this circumstance.

Please.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you installing on your system-wide Python or in a virtualenv? I recommend the second way…

Comment: Sure, but this is system-wide, because a client of mine has an erp instance system-wide, he's not that expert, but I have to resolve it this way...

Comment: "I was trying to install `hashlib` python module" - *install* `hashlib`? `hashlib` is part of the standard library. From the stack traces you're showing us, it looks like you have some other weird thing called `hashlib.py` that's name-colliding with the standard library module and screwing things up. What's this thing coming from?

Comment: Are you looking at [this thing](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hashlib) on PyPI? That's for Python 2.4 and older. You're on 2.7; you don't need it.

Comment: I don't have any idea, this a gcloud instance from a client, so I don't really know, never had this problem before, if I do this: ´locate hashlib.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.pyc
/usr/lib/python3.5/hashlib.py
´ but really, I don't know, maybe I should delete them?

Comment: There's Odoo v9 on this instance, but I don't think is related, it was working fine, I think this is coming from the easy_install command, I coleague told me to install hashlib but I think he's wrong on that one, should I delete that file?

Comment: Don't delete those files. You might need to do some other cleanup, but the files `locate` reported look like the standard library versions, which you should keep.

Comment: Do You know how can I cleanup this? I just installed python 2.7.6 but nothing, still same error

Comment: Don't do anything to files under /usr/lib, but do move hashlib.py (and hashlib.pyc, if it exists) _from the current directory_ into another one, such as /tmp. (Moving instead of deleting so that you can put them back if they turn out to be needed, though I doubt it.) While you have hashlib.py or hashlib.pyc in the current directory, Python will try to use those instead of the proper ones in the standard library.

Comment: Also move or remove /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hashlib-20081119-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg. Both pip and easy_install rely on hashlib working, so until you make sure that Python uses the right version of hashlib, they won't work.

Comment: Ultra awesome @deltab, Thank You

Comment: You can add it as an answer if You please :)